# Mysql Query clearing a row instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea why this is acting this way, I did echo out `$sqll` in my code and it shows all the right information but when it goes back to the page with the information it is blank.

Here is the script

```
<?php
include("header.php"); 
include("sidebar.php");

$memberon = $_GET['user'];
$getmember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='".$memberon."'");
$member = mysql_fetch_array($getmember);
?>       

    <h2>Edit User</h2> 

<?php
$points = asql($_POST['points']);
$cash = asql($_POST['cash']);
$banned = asql($_POST['banned']);
$completed = asql($_POST['completed']);
$confirm= asql($_POST['confirm']);
$referral= asql($_POST['ref']);
$email= asql($_POST['email']);
$username= asql($_POST['username']);
$fname= asql($_POST['fname']);
$lname= asql($_POST['lname']);
$add= asql($_POST['address']);
$state= asql($_POST['state']);
$country= asql($_POST['country']);
$postal= asql($_POST['postal']);
$apt= asql($_POST['suite']);
$city= asql($_POST['city']);
$phone= asql($_POST['phone']);
$dob= asql($_POST['dob']);


if ($_POST['subm']) {
if($points <> $member['points'] || $cash <> $member['current_b']){
$final_report = "Checking";
print"This users balance has been updated, please input your pass code to confirm these changes <br />
<form method='post' action=''><input type='hidden' name='points' value='$points'><input type='hidden' name='cash' value='$cash'><input type='hidden' name='banned' value='$banned'><input type='hidden' name='confirm' value='$confirm'><input type='hidden' name='ref' value='$referral'><input type='hidden' name='email' value='$email'><input type='hidden' name='fname' value='$fname'><input type='hidden' name='lname' value='$lname'><input type='hidden' name='address' value='$add'><input type='hidden' name='state' value='$state'><input type='hidden' name='country' value='$country'><input type='hidden' name='postal' value='$postal'><input type='hidden' name='suite' value='$apt'><input type='hidden' name='city' value='$city'><input type='hidden' name='phone' value='$phone'><input type='hidden' name='dob' value='$dob'><input type='password' name='passcode' /><input type='submit' name='pcheck' value='Sumbit' /></form>";
}
else
{
$final_report = "";
}
if($final_report == NULL){
$updatemembers = mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET points='$points', current_b='$cash', level='$banned', email_check='$confirm', referral='$referral', username='$username', fname='$fname', lname='$lname', email='$email', address='$add', state='$state', country='$country', postal='$postal', suite='$apt', city='$city', phone='$phone', dob='$dob' WHERE username='".$memberon."'") or die(mysql_error());
     print "You Have Successfully Updated this Information";    
     header("Refresh: 2;url=edit.php?user=".$memberon."");  
}
}

if($_POST['pcheck']){
$pchecki = asql($_POST['passcode']);
$pchecks = md5($pchecki);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM panel_access WHERE psn = '".$_SESSION['aname']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$checkar = mysql_fetch_array($check);
$final_report = "Checking.";
if($pchecks != $checkar['change_ab']){
$final_report = "That password is incorrect.";
     print "".$final_report.""; 
     header("Refresh: 2;url=edit.php?user=".$memberon."");
}
else
{
$final_report = "";
}
if($final_report == NULL){
$sqll = "UPDATE accounts SET points='".$points."', current_b='".$cash."', level='".$banned."', email_check='".$confirm."', referral='".$referral."', username='".$username."', fname='".$fname."', lname='".$lname."', email='".$email."', address='".$add."', state='".$state."', country='".$country."', postal='".$postal."', suite='".$apt."', city='".$city."', phone='".$phone."', dob='".$dob."' WHERE username='".$memberon."'";
$updatemember = mysql_query($sqll) or die(mysql_error());
     print "You Have Successfully Updated this Information ".$sqll."";  
     header("Refresh: 2;url=edit.php?user=".$memberon."");  
}
}

    if(!isset($_POST['subm']) && !isset($_POST['pcheck']))
    {
 ?>                   
<div class='form'>
         <form action='' method='post'><input type=hidden name=subm value=1>
                <div class="element">
                        <label for='email'>Email:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $member['email'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='username'>Username:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $member['username'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='ip'>IP Address:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='ip' id='ip' value='<?php echo $member['ip'] ?>' size='54' readonly='readonly' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='banned'>Banned: <font color='red' size='1'><b>1=No 2=Yes</b></font></label>
                        <input type='text' name='banned' id='banned' value='<?php echo $member['level'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='confirm'>E-Mail Confirmed: <font color='red' size='1'>0=No 1=Yes</font></label>
                        <input type='text' name='confirm' id='confirm' value='<?php echo $member['email_check'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='ref'>Referral:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='ref' id='ref' value='<?php echo $member['referral'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='points'>Points:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='points' id='points' value='<?php echo $member['points'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='cash'>Cash:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='cash' id='cash' value='<?php echo $member['current_b'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='fname'>First Name:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' value='<?php echo $member['fname'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='lname'>Last Name:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='lname' id='lname' value='<?php echo $member['lname'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='phone'>Phone:</label>
                        <input type='tel' name='phone' id='phone' value='<?php echo $member['phone'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='dob'>Date of Birth:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='dob' id='dob' value='<?php echo $member['dob'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='address'>Address:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='address' id='address' value='<?php echo $member['address'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='suite'>Suite/Apt.:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='suite' id='suite' value='<?php echo $member['suite'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='country'>Country:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='country' id='country' value='<?php echo $member['country'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='state'>State:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='state' id='state' value='<?php echo $member['state'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='city'>City:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='city' id='city' value='<?php echo $member['city'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
                   <div class="element">
                        <label for='postal'>Postal Code:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='postal' id='postal' value='<?php echo $member['postal'] ?>' size='54' />
                    </div>
<?php
                     print"<dl class='submit'>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
                     </dl>





         </form>
         </div> "; 
      }
      include("footer.php");
?>
```

On a side note I know that `mysql_query` and the likes are in the process of being deprecated, I want to note that I did not write this, just doing some editing for a client, and this part is happening to be a pain in the rear.

Also its only the query in `if($_POST['pcheck'])` that isn't working, the first query for `if($_POST['subm']` works fine

Comment: Two things; this is rife with SQL injection vulnerabilities and the *mysql* extension has been deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead

Comment: @Phil please read my entire post before making a comment, I already know this, but the client is paying me to edit not write, so I am adding stuff in as it is now.

Comment: Are you sure all your input variables are set correctly? Also, you should exit after the `header()` calls so that you don't inadvertently execute code below them.

Comment: @siride Yes they are set correctly because when I echo out `$sqll` all of the information is right. Also its only the query in `if($_POST['pcheck'])` that isn't working, the first query for `if($_POST['subm']` works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an empty string at the end. This doesn't hurt, but it has no purpose either.

You redirect the page to `edit.php?user=$memberon`, but `$memberon` isn't set when you get a POST request. You can have either GET or POST, but not both.

I would guess, you must redirect to

```
edit.php?user=$username
```

Comment: The redirects work fine because all of the form actions are blank so it doesn't have any affect on the url therefore `$memberon` stays in place so it can pull it.

Comment: @kira423 What I mean is, when the form is submitted, you get all the `$_POST` variables, but not the `$_GET` variables. And then you have all the form values, but *not* the `$memberon`. And this results in `edit.php?user=`